# Get cpu utilization percentage using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have executed the below command in command prompt.

**Input:**

```
 C:\>@for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p% 
    8%
    %
```

I have written the code to get only 8% in batch script like below,

```
call :Harddisk
call :CPU
Echo ^</TABLE^> ^</BODY^> ^</HTML^> >> %opfile%
pause
exit /b

:CPU
set wmih=@for /f skip=1 %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %p% |Find /c /v ":"
ECHO wmih
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in ('"%wmih%"') do (
   Echo ^<TR^> ^<TD^> >> %opfile%
   Echo CPU Utilization: %%a >> %opfile%
   Echo ^</TD^> ^</TR^> >> %opfile%
)

exit /b
```

I'm not getting proper output. Please help me to sort it out.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value ^|find "="') do echo set p=%%i
set p=%p:~0,-1%
echo %p%
```

Comment: No, it works better because the `echo %p%` ends its work when the first CR is found in the variable content. In this case `find` does not change the line ending. To test, include after your code `cmd /v:on /c "echo !p!...!p!"` and see the output.

Comment: grrr. I'm going to *hate* that ugly `wmic`output... So `%p%`still contains that <CR>. But can be removed. Changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep your structure

```
:CPU
set "wmih=@for /f "usebackq skip^^^=2 tokens^^^=2 delims^^^=^^^," %%p in (`wmic cpu get loadpercentage^^^,version /format^^^:csv`) do @echo(%%p%%"
ECHO %wmih%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in ('"%wmih%"') do (
   >>%opfile% Echo ^<TR^> ^<TD^> 
   >>%opfile% Echo CPU Utilization: %%a 
   >>%opfile% Echo ^</TD^> ^</TR^> 
)
```

To be able to store the command inside a variable and then pass it to the `for` command, that will spawn another `cmd` instance to execute the command, you need a lot of scape characters just to handle the command execution.

It can be made easier

```
:CPU
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic cpu get loadpercentage^,version /format^:csv'
) do (
   >>%opfile% Echo ^<TR^> ^<TD^> 
   >>%opfile% Echo CPU Utilization: %%a%%
   >>%opfile% Echo ^</TD^> ^</TR^> 
)
```

In both cases, to remove the aditional CR character at the end of the retrieved value, the query request the output in csv format with an aditional field, so, the needed data is not at the end of the line and the value will not include the ending CR